# Error in my code from transferring data from flask variable in python to html file

Tags: python, html, variables, flask, return

I am creating a flask web application which asks users to complete a quiz through a form and collect data from each session. I use a main.py file, 1 html file with the quiz, and then another one which is supposed to display dynamic results. When the submit button is clicked, it automatically directs users to the second html page with their results. It is my intention to display results based upon what options the user clicks. I attempted to accomplish this by:

1. Collecting data:

```
    session["symptom1"] = form.symptom1.data
```

2. Writing this into a file

```
    user_data.write(form.symptom1.data)
```

3. Reading file contents into a variable (3 characters into each variable)

```
    data1 = user_data.read(3)
```

4. Assigning a Boolean value to a python variable based upon the data using a conditional:

```
    if data1 == "op3" or data1 == "op4":
      global adhd1
      adhd1 = True
```

5. Rendering this to an html file:

```
    return render_template("takethequiz.html", form = form,adhd1=adhd1,adhd2=adhd2,adhd3=adhd3,adhd4=adhd4)
```

6. Creating a conditional in a second html file (treatmentplan.html)=

```
 {% if adhd1 == True %}
 Use productivity apps to increase your focus
 {% else %}
 Great job! You are skilled at staying on task!
 {% endif %}
```

However this does not do anything. Meaning, no matter what I click, the treatment plan is always set to adhd1 = False. How do I combat this?
**Code Screenshots on Google Doc:** https://docs.google.com/document/d/1uF1Q-zfKNx-d5jzbaIK_BKGbLRm0tCGgaz92-V2hDjE/edit?usp=sharing
Thank you!

Comment: When you get an internal server error, check the server log. There's probably a Python syntax error somewhere.

Comment: @Bamar There is no syntax error, it just does not work. Meaning, no matter what I click, the treatment plan is always set to adhd1 = False.

Comment: Internal server error is a generic error that means the script failed in some way. Without any more details we can only guess what the problem.

Comment: @Bamar, sorry I forgot to clarify, the Internal Service Error went away. But the variable data is not moving in between the python and html file.